Project tiles layout makes topnav size change
I'm new to web development and am trying to make a very basic personal page, containing a home page with simple text, a projects page with a project tile layout and a blog. I'm encountering a problem with the size (and therefor position) of my topnav bar when i switch between the project tiles page and the home page. When I'm on the homepage, the body elements have a slightly larger width compared to the projects tile page. Because of that the bar moves when I switch between pages.
I figured out that the tile layout influences the topnav bar size, but I don't see how I can solve it. Do you guys have any suggestions? Below is the snippet of code and the CSS. I used an online tutorial to make the responsive tiles layout: How to fix this complex CSS grid of photos based on 4 columns?


```css
body {
    margin: 4px;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;

}

/* Top nav design */

.topnav {
    margin: auto;
    background-color:white;
    padding:0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.topnav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    /* background-color: blue;         */
}

.topnav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    color:black;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.topnav ul li a:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/* Projects page */

.project-tiles {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
grid-gap: 56px 40px;
margin: 35px;
list-style: none;
}

.tile a img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  /* padding: 20px; */
}

/* 1st photo = 2 columns, 2 first rows */
.tile:nth-child(11n +1){
  grid-area:span 2/span 2;
}

.tile:nth-child(11n + 10){
  grid-area: 3/3/span 2/span 2;
}

.tile:nth-child(11n + 11){
  grid-column: span 4;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.tile:nth-child(11n +1),
.tile:nth-child(11n +4),
.tile:nth-child(11n +5){
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.tile:hover {
  transform: scale(1.02);
}

.tile a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
<html lang="nl">
  <head>
    <title>Website name | Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  </head>
  
  <body>

    <div class="topnav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="active-page">Home</a></li>         
          <li><a href="projecten/index.html">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="blog/index.html">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
        
      </div>
      <hr>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        

        <p> Some text</p>
          
        <p>Some more text </p>

       <hr/>
    
   <footer><a href = "contact.html">Contact me</a></footer>
  </body>
</html>

**For the projects page I have the following HTML:**

<html lang="nl">
  <head>
    <title>Website name | Projects</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="topnav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>         
          <li><a href="../projecten/index.html" class="active-page">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="../blog/index.html">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
        
    </div>
    <hr>
    <h1>Projects</h1>

 <ul class="project-tiles">
 
  <li class="tile">
    <a href="project1.html"><img src=""></a>
  </li>
  <li class="tile">
    <a href="project1.html"><img src=""></a>
  </li>
  <li class="tile">
    <a href="project1.html"><img src=""></a>
  </li>
  <li class="tile">
    <a href="project1.html"><img src=""></a>
  </li>
  <li class="tile">
    <a href="project1.html"><img src=""></a>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <hr>
    <footer><a href = "../contact.html">Contact me</a></footer>
    
   </body>
</html>



It took me quite a while to figure out that the project tiles (the UL element) was influencing the position. The size of the UL is somehow smaller compared to the body on the other pages, and it seems to be deciding the whole page size. After that I tried to adjust the margin of several items but it doesn't seem to do anything.
To give an example:
The homepage and the size of the top nav

The projects page and the somewhat smaller topnav bar (like 9 pixels or so)


Add code as Code Snippet so that it can be run, also the issue should be reproducible

I cannot reproduce this. On my local device (Chrome) both navbars have a width of 988 pixels.

By trying to figure out to add a code snippet and running the code above on my local machine and checking the difference, I figured out the error is not reproducible because it's the img inside the image tag that is causing the problem. After removing the image from the img tag the problem dissapeared, however eventually I want to have images in it again. Could it be that I'm using the img tag wrong inside the project tiles page?
